# Magento 2: How to Restrict Customer Email by Domain?

Tags: magento2, customer, custom

In my Magento 2 site, I am looking for a way to restrict signing up a user account with all email domains(eg Gmail,Hotmail) except for 2 email domains.

I found a guide that said to go to

`/var/www/html/app/code/Magento/Customer/etc/adminhtml/system.xml`

to add in new fields in Customer Configuration(`Stores -> Configuration -> Customers -> Customer Configuration`) that will allow me to configure email domains that I can block.

However, editing the system.xml file does not change anything in Customer Configuration, I have tested this by deleting the entire "Create New Account Options", and have refreshed the Magento Cache.

I am running Magento 2.1.7.

Please advice on what I have done incorrectly. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple extension should helps you to manage customer restriction. 
https://github.com/magekey/module-customer-restriction

Comment: I'm sorry, after following the instructions in the link, the extension don't seem to have been installed. Running the composer command works, but running setup:upgrade don't lists out the customer restriction module. Continuing the steps, the extension doesn't appear in stores -> Customer either. It also doesn't show up on my lists of installed extensions. Please advice. Thank you

Comment: you need move to magento root directory and run 
**composer require magekey/module-customer-restriction**

Comment: after composer work done you need to follow deployment instruction.

Comment: first make sure you have installed module, check composer.json, you should see line  magekey/module-customer-restriction, and of course should be new directory in vendor folder.

Comment: of course best way use composer, but you always can move module to app/code folder. So if you have any issues with composer just create app/code/MageKey/CustomerRestriction and move all files under this directory. don't forget to deploy it.

Comment: Just fyi about composer ... if you have no global composer installation you need to use this line **php composer.phar require magekey/module-customer-restriction**

Comment: I'm deeply sorry to trouble you, especially after its been so many days. After installing this module, I realized that the Component Manager (System -> Web Setup Wizard -> Component Manager) isn't working anymore, it loops on "please wait" message. Uninstalling the module solves this issue. What can I do to have both working? Please advice. Thank you.

Comment: It's Magento 2 Issue https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4756. You need to update setup module code (temporary solution) or just move module to app/code folder and remove it from composer.

Comment: This issue will be solved in version 2.2

Comment: If I would move the module to app/code folder, I would create additional folder, MageKey and within it, CustomerRestriction and move all files under that directory, correct? What command do I use, as i am unsure of the module name?

Comment: yes put all files under app/code/MageKey/CustomerRestriction then remove line in composer and run composer update.

Answer (score 3):

app/code/Company/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost">
    <plugin name="restrictCustomerEmail"
            type="Company\Module\Model\Plugin\Controller\Account\RestrictCustomerEmail"/>
</type>
```

app/code/Company/Module/Model/Plugin/Controller/Account/RestrictCustomerEmail.php

```
<?php
 namespace Company\Module\Model\Plugin\Controller\Account;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory;
use Magento\Framework\UrlFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface;


class RestrictCustomerEmail
{

/** @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface */
protected $urlModel;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory
 */
protected $resultRedirectFactory;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface
 */
protected $messageManager;

/**
 * RestrictCustomerEmail constructor.
 * @param UrlFactory $urlFactory
 * @param RedirectFactory $redirectFactory
 * @param ManagerInterface $messageManager
 */
public function __construct(
    UrlFactory $urlFactory,
    RedirectFactory $redirectFactory,
    ManagerInterface $messageManager

)
{
    $this->urlModel = $urlFactory->create();
    $this->resultRedirectFactory = $redirectFactory;
    $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
}

/**
 * @param \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost $subject
 * @param \Closure $proceed
 * @return mixed
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
 */
public function aroundExecute(
    \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost $subject,
    \Closure $proceed
)
{
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request */
    $email = $subject->getRequest()->getParam('email');
    list($nick, $domain) = explode('@', $email, 2);
    if (in_array($domain, ['163.com', 'mail.ru'], true)) {

        $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(
            'Registration is disabled for you domain'
        );
        $defaultUrl = $this->urlModel->getUrl('*/*/create', ['_secure' => true]);
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();

        return $resultRedirect->setUrl($defaultUrl);

    }
    return $proceed();
 }
}
```

You can check this post out it may help you. It also contains the answer. for reference.

[Magento 2: Restrict customer registration by specific mail extension](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/157742/magento-2-restrict-customer-registration-by-specific-mail-extension)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/99496)

Comment: @FabianSchmengler Sure will take care of that thanks.