# How to block @xxxx.ru email from registering on my magento2 site

Tags: magento2, email, migration, registration

Since I migrated from M1 to M2.1.9, I have been bombarded with spam registrations from `.ru` domains. Is there a way of preventing this without a module ? I found this : [Magento 2: Restrict customer registration by specific mail extension](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/157742/magento-2-restrict-customer-registration-by-specific-mail-extension) 
which is totally beyond my competence...

Comment: If you don't want allow login to .ru domain then you can  write script to set deactivated flag by using customer attribute. It may help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento 2 has added a new layer of protection for the Customer Portal area same as Magento 1. CAPTCHA, which is disabled by default, can be enabled from the Dashboard panel.
This feature can help blocking spam and bots from logging into your website and it will effectively increase the security of the store.

CAPTCHA can be configured from backend and you can arrange whether to force it to each login or limit the feature to pop up only after a few failed logins. CAPTCHA prerequisite can be enabled/disabled by the Administrator for the following forms:

- Create user
- Login
- Forgot password
- Check Out as Guest
- Register during Checkout
- Contact Us
- Change password

For more detail [click here](https://magemojo.com/kb/knowledge-base/how-to-enable-customer-login-or-register-captcha-in-magento-2/).

Comment: thx a lot for your help

Comment: @urbansurfers - Happy to help. Keep helping :)