# Magento 2 change signup url

Tags: magento2

I'm getting lots of fake customer signup with .ur email addresses and Russian charters. I suspect there are be.

Is it possible to change the default signup URL?

Comment: Use the Captch on registration page and other pages to avoid this in future

Answer (score 1):

We don't need to change this url. There is already an answer [Magento 2: Restrict customer registration by specific mail extension](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/157742/magento-2-restrict-customer-registration-by-specific-mail-extension/158088#158088). We can improve this solution by **adding a config with an email suffix list**.

Answer (score 0):

Now using Captch as suggested. This has stopped the problem