# Spambot protection fake customer registration

Tags: magento2, php, email, form-validation

I want to reject all the registration of fake customers with a specific domain email.
Since the spambot can send the data through POST it does not enough create a new data-validate rule in the register.phtml file, so the validation should be server-side. Captcha is a bad option, I must avoid it.
Confirm registration email is active but I want to prevent to send an email.
How to do that? What the Observer is useful?

Comment: With a specific domain email. Did you try with https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/157742/magento-2-restrict-customer-registration-by-specific-mail-extension/158088#158088?

Comment: It doesn't work, the plugin is not executed. Does it need a registration.php file?

Comment: Do you know how to create a new module? You should need to add more files.

Comment: Yes I know, but I thought it was not necessary because it was not mentioned by the magento 2 plugin documentation. I added the preg_match function to match the email with the pattern of an external file, line by line. Thanks.

Comment: You can use this module for Spam Control https://www.oscprofessionals.com/magento-extension/spam-killer-magento2-module/ . We can easily restrict any parameters from this module. Registration Page as well as newsletter Area.